# On what basis are chapters divided in Pirke Avot?

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof

Is there any sort of thematic basis for how chapters are divided in Avot?  Who divided it into chapters? Is it chronologcial?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93594/759